# According to TLD tag test must be empty

Tags: java, jsp, chat

I have this jsp file in my college project, and when trying to run it, I'm getting this error: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute test does not accept any expressions. What should I do to fix it? Thanks for your appretitation.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat Joined</title>
  </head>

 <body>
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}">   <-- here error happens
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.send!=null}">
      <c:set var="chat"
      value="${chat}<b>${param.uid}:</b>${param.text}<br />"
       scope="application" />
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${param.clear!=null}">
      <c:set var="chat" value="" scope="application" />
    </c:when>
  </c:choose>
</c:if>

<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>User: 
        <c:out value="${param.uid}" />
        </h3>

        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${chat}" escapeXml="false" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <hr />

        <form method="post">Message:
        <input type="text" name="text" size="20" />

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />

        <input type="submit" name="refresh" value="Refresh" />

        <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear" />

        <input type="hidden" name="uid"
        value="<c:out value="${param.uid}"/>" />

        <br />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in declaration instead of what you are using now

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`